# Firebase Real Time Database rules

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

in my Android app I want to implement real-time database by Firebase.

The rules are not very simply:

> --AUTHOR: **write** periodicals strings
>
> ----ADMIN: **create** a "chat/room" and invite friends
>
> ------MEMBER: **read** periodicals strings and **write** own data.

Also:

> ADMIN is also a MEMBER.
>
> Every "chat/room" is about 10 MEMBERS.
>
> MEMBER can **write** its own data and **read** periodical strings (by author) and the data of the
>   other 9 members.

Actually, my rules' code is:

```
{
   "rules": {
    "chats": {
      "$chatID": {
        "messages": {
          ".read": "data.parent().child('members').child(auth.uid).exists()",
          ".write": "data.parent().child('members').child(auth.uid).val() == 'owner' || data.parent().child('members').child(auth.uid).val()=='chatter'"
        },
        "members": {
          ".read": "data.child(auth.uid).val() == 'owner'",
          ".write": "data.child(auth.uid).val() == 'owner' ||(!data.exists()&&newData.child(auth.uid).val()=='owner')"
        },
        "pending": {
          ".read": "data.parent().child('members').child(auth.uid).val() === 'owner'",
          ".write": "data.parent().child('members').child(auth.uid).val() === 'owner'",
          "$uid": {
            ".write": "$uid === auth.uid && !data.exists() && !data.parent().parent().child('members').child($uid).exists()"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I'm not able to work with code. Anyone can help me? Thanks.